# Newbie question: Creating a custom control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have an ASP.Net site, in which I am using a ListView with a Datapager. Apparently there is a bug with the Datapager, where it crashes if there is an empty ampersand (&) in the querystring. This is a known issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=357344&wa=wsignin1.0#tabs

I see that there is a workaround given, but did not understand how to implement it. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Also, I see that this issue is marked as resolved. Any idea where I can find the updated version of this control?

Wild Thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement the workaround, you need to subclass the DataPager control.  In other words, create a new class that descends from DataPager.  Then paste the code that mysterious.e-theorrigional wrote in the workaround into the class.

Then, instead of using DataPager, you use this new class.  That should solve your issues.

As to the second part of your question, how to get the updates: It was most likely fixed in .Net 4.0.  In order to use that, you'll need VS2010.  I can't guarantee that's where it was fixed, but given the work item status, that makes the most sense.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thanks for your help. I have created the class, and am copying the code over. I am converting mysterious.e-theorrigional's code into VB from C#. I have run into a problem with this line:

Builder.Query = String.Join("&", CleanValues.Select(p >= p.Key + "=" + p.Value).ToArray())

I get the error "option strict on prohibits operands of type object for operator '+'"

Also, once I have created the class, how will I replace the calls to the datapager control with this class?

Thanks!

Comment: @Wild Thing: you might want to look at http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100103-1.aspx  and http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Custom-Server-Controls.aspx

Comment: It worked! It worked! Thanks for the help and the links, Chris!